# Continuous linear bijection of a Banach space is a homeomorphism

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have seen an example of a continuous linear bijection $f:S\to S$, where $S$ was a normed linear space, such that the inverse function $f^{-1}$ was not continuous,as it was unbounded.The norm on $S$ was not complete .

It was then stated that if $T$ is a Banach space and $g:T\to T$ is a continuous linear bijection, then $g^{-1}$ is continuous, so that $g$ is a homeomorphism.It said this followed from the Uniform Boundedness Principle. I have been unable to see how to do this.

How do you prove that $g^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: This is a consequence of the open mapping theorem : if $T,S$ are Banach and $f : T \to S$ is a surjective linear continuous application, then the image of every open set in $T$ by $f$ is also an open set in $S$. But the OMT is not a trivial consequence of the uniform boundedness principle and needs some work ! Usually, the OMT is even proved independently.